# Recursive complexity with change of variable

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation

I face a problem with computing a complexity. 
I have this equality : $P(u) = (\sqrt{u}+1)P(\sqrt{u}) + \theta(\sqrt{u})$

And I want to prove that $P(u) = O(u)$

This is how I process :

I put $m = \lg\lg u \implies P(u) = P(2^{2^{m}}) = (2^{2^{m-1}}+1)P(2^{2^{m-1}}) + \theta(2^{2^{m-1}})$

Now, I consider $S(m)$ that is : $S(m) = P(2^{2^{m}}) = mS(m-1) + \theta(m-1)$

And here I have a problem. I obtain a factorial complexity and I don't know how to integrate $\lg$ to prove the equality $P(u) = O(u)$

Some advice ?

Comment: Please check your calculation in switching variables from u to m.  If you define S(m)=P(2^(2^m)), then you should not get S(m)=mS(m−1)+Θ(m−1).

Comment: You may have right. Actually it's useless because I fall on the same formula as to the begining ... with squares

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto May be that the $\lg \lg u$ is a wrong way to slove it ?

Comment: Considering S(m)=P(2^(2^m)) is a good step, but you need some more calculation to say something useful about S(m).  One way to proceed is to write S(m) in terms of S(m−1) (which you attempted but your calculation is incorrect; try to correct it), then write S(m) in terms of S(m−2), then write S(m) in terms of S(m−3), to see a possible pattern.  If you see a pattern there, then you can use mathematical induction to prove that this observed pattern is indeed true.

Comment: But before that, I think that it is easy to think if you remove the asymptotic notations from the assumption; the assumption implies that there is a constant a>0 such that for all u, it holds that $P(u)\le(\sqrt{u}+1)P(\sqrt{u})+a\sqrt{u}$.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto right, I can major with $a$, but for the substitution I can't figure out how to do. I can replace $P(2^{2^{m-1}})$ with $S(m-1)$, but that's all :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following your suggestion, let $S(m) = P(2^{2^m})$, and let's forget about the $+1$ in the recurrence. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
S(m) &= 2^{2^{m-1}}S(m-1) + \Theta(2^{2^{m-1}}) \\ &=
\Theta(2^{2^{m-1}} + 2^{2^{m-1}+2^{m-2}}) + 2^{2^{m-1}+2^{m-2}} S(m-2) \\ &= \cdots \\ &=
\Theta(2^{2^{m-1}} + 2^{2^{m-1}+2^{m-2}} + \cdots + 2^{2^{m-1}+\cdots+1}) \\ &=
%\Theta(2^{2^m-1}(1+2^{-1}+2^{-1-2}+\cdots+2^{-1-2-\cdots-2^{m-2}})) \\ &=
\Theta(2^{2^m}(2^{-1}+2^{-2}+\cdots+2^{-2^{m-1}})) = \Theta(2^{2^m}).
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: It would be better to label a hint as a hint.  For a solution, you cannot “forget about the +1.”

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto Well, if you can prove that "$+1$" does not change the result then you can, but that is of course missing, too.